# Change Oultook 365 Group Calendar Permissions

Tags: powershell, outlook, office365

Is it possible to give members of the Oultook group read-only access to calendar events?
I want my team members to only be able to view events in the calendar, but not be able to edit them.

I decided to use the Exchange Online module for Powershell, since I did not find the basic tools in Outlook for this

Using command:

```
Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $MailBoxId -GroupMailbox
```

I get the following content:

```
FolderName           User                 AccessRights                                                            SharingPermissionFlags                                                 
----------           ----                 ------------                                                            ----------------------                                                 
Top of Informatio... Default              {None}                                                                                                                                         
Top of Informatio... Anonymous            {None}                                                                                                                                         
Top of Informatio... Owner@local          {ReadItems, CreateItems, EditOwnedItems, DeleteOwnedItems...}                                                                                  
Top of Informatio... Member@local         {Author}
```

Question! How do I remove or replace the permissions for the **Member@local** user?

If using command:

```
Remove-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $MailBoxId -User Member@local
```

or

```
Remove-MailboxPermission -Identity $MailBoxId -GroupMailbox -User Member@local -AccessRights Author
```

I got this:

```
The operation couldn't be performed because object '$MailBoxId####' couldn't be found on 'mycompany.prod.outlook.com'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found another solution and everything turned out to be much easier

```
Set-UnifiedGroup -Identity $GroupID -CalendarMemberReadOnly
```